# Improving a simple trig model

Tags: python, predictive-modeling, model-selection, implementation

I have [some data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pgcnjfidld4q4b2/example_data.npy?dl=0) which I know is well approximated as a trig function, and I can fit it with `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` as follows:

```
from __future__import division
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit 



#Load the data
data = np.load('example_data.npy')

x = data[:,0]
y = data[:,1]

#Define the parametric trig function:

def trig_function(t,A,B,omega,offset):
return A*np.sin(omega*t) + B*np.cos(omega*t) + offset 

#Define fitting procedure
def fit(x,y):


    sigma = np.ones(len(t))
    sigma[[0, -1]] = 1e-1 #weight the end points

    func = trig_function #define the fitting function

    #Some guesses for initial parameter values
    dA = (y.max() + y.min()) / 2
    y_shifted = y - offset
    omega = np.pi * np.sum(y_shifted[:-1] * y_shifted[1:] < 0) / (t.max() - t.min())
    p0 = (dA,dA, omega,dA)


    #Do the fit
    popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x,y,p0=p0,sigma=sigma)

    #return fitted data
    return func(x, *popt)

#Define plotting environment
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(24,10)) 
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((2,1), (0,0))
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((2,1), (1,0),sharex=ax1) 

#get fit data
y_approx = fit(x,y)

#Plot both solutions and relative error
ax1.plot(x,y)
ax1.plot(x,y_approx)
dy = (y_approx - y)/y
ax2.plot(x,dy)
```

This works pretty well:[image]

However there is clearly still some feature not being accounted for by the model, especially close to the minima, as evidenced by the peaks in the relative error.

**Can anyone advise** how the model (i.e. the parametric trig function) could be further developed to properly account for the behaviour?

Thanks

Comment: It looks to me like the error has a component which has twice the frequency of the main cycle in the your data, you could add A2*np.sin(omega2*t) + B2*np.cos(omega2*t) - (basically you've fitted a truncated fourier sequence, if you keep adding terms at higher frequency your approximation should improve)

Comment: Yes that was also my thought, except adding more terms doesn't seem to improve the fit at all?